# Список последних видео Youtube в XML

Tags: php

Как найти список последних видео определенного канала на youtube? Раньше был доступен по ссылке:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/*канал*/uploads
```

Comment: Кажется Youtube API версия 2.0 уже не работает, надо использовать версию 3.0. Вот [ответ на английском SO про использование нового API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13504899/546661).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добрый день. Данное `api` считается устаревшим и более не поддерживается. В настроящий момент все вынесено в один сервис `developers.google`

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: А можете подсказать - как получить список видео с новым сервисом, если не сложно

Comment: для начала Вам необходимо иметь активную учетную запись на developers.google. затем Ваше приложение должно быть зарегестрированно там же. Ссылка на описание работы api указал. Возможно кто-то недавно работал с этим сервисом и распишет как должен выглядеть Ваш запрос, я с этим сталкивался только когда мое приложение перестало работать и пришлось переводить мой функционал на новое апи. весной если не ошибаюсь gdata.youtube.com прикрыли

Comment: Peter Olson ответил на Ваш вопрос. Вам лишь подключить осталось